# Comparison theorem for ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Here is something I'm trying to prove:

> **Conjecture:** Suppose $f'(x) \leq \phi(f(x), x)$ and $f(a)=\alpha$. Suppose $g'(x)=\phi(g(x),x)$ and $g(a)\geq \alpha$. Then $f(x)\leq
>  g(x)\,\,\forall x$.

It definitely seems like it should be true, and I don't think we even need continuity of $\phi$.

(**Edit:** a user has correctly pointed out that we should require $\phi$ be locally Lipshitz in the first variable, uniformly with respect to the second variable. Let's add that assumption.)

I can prove it in the case that the inequality is strict. I'll place my proof below the fold. How can I extend it to weak inequality?

If it's wrong, I'd love to see a counterexample. A reference is fine; I have the book by Teschl, for example.

A similar question with stronger assumptions was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158332/comparison-theorem-for-systems-of-ode).

---

**Proposition:** Suppose Suppose $f'(x) < \phi(f(x), x)$ and $f(a)=\alpha$. Suppose $g'(x)=\phi(g(x),x)$ and $g(a)\geq \alpha$. Then $f(x)\leq
 g(x)\,\,\forall x$.

**Proof:** Suppose not. Suppose WLOG there is a $b>a$ such that $f(b)>g(b)$. Let $c:=\inf \{x>a:f(x)>g(x)\}$. By definition of the derivative we have $f'(c)\geq g'(c)$, a contradiction, since $f'(c)<\phi(f(c),c)=\phi(g(c),c))=g'(c)$.

Comment: Theorem 1.3 in Teschl.

Comment: There is no theorem 1.3, only up to lemma 1.2 in that chapter, if you meant the book "Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems"

Comment: shouldt $f'<g'$ also give this? whats point of involving the function $\phi$ and then put $f$ in it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Denote $h=f-g$. Assume there is $b>a$ such that $h(b)>0$. Since $h$ is continuous and $h(a)\leq0$ thus there exists $c\in[a,b)$ such that $h(x)>0$ for $x\in(c,b]$ and $h(c)=0$ ($c=\inf\{d\in[a,b]: f|_{[d,b]}>0\}$). We thus get that for $x\in[c,b]$
\begin{align*}
h'\leq\Phi(f(x),x)-\Phi(g(x),x)\leq L|f(x)-g(x)|=Lh,
\end{align*}
from which $h(b)\leq h(c)e^{L(b-c)}=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Are you not using what we need to prove in order to conclude?

Comment: No, I am not - the conclusion follows from a special case of the Gronwall lemma.  To prove it You divide by $h$, observe that the LHS is a derivative of $\ln{h}$ and integrate both sides of the inequality form $c$ to $b$.

Comment: Ok, true. Somewhat surprising you need to resort to Gronwall Lemma to prove this: I wonder if the argument could be shortened further.

Comment: Very nice proof :) I also wonder if it is possible to prove the claim directly (i.e. without contradiction).. I needed a slight improvement of this for my purposes and thought I might as well share it here. Suppose that $f'(x)=\Phi(f(x),x), f(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=\Phi(g(x),x)+r(x), g(0)=0$ where $r(x)>0$ for $x>0$, then $f(x)<g(x)$ for $x>0$. Proof: By @MarcinMalogrosz's argument we have $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for $x\geq 0$. Now if $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ for some $x_0>0$ then $h'(x_0)=f'(x_0)-g'(x_0) =-r(x_0) <0$ so $h(x) =f(x)-g(x)<0$ for $x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0)$ for some $\delta>0$ by calculus, a contradiction.

Comment: +1 Very nice. ${}$

Answer (score 9):

Without Lipschitz continuity of $\Phi$, it is false. For a counterexample take $\Phi(y,x)=(3/2)y^{1/3}$ and let $g(x)=0$, $f(x)=x^{3/2}$, and $a=0$.

(This is the standard example for nonuniqueness of solutions with a non-Lipshitz right hand side.)

Comment: Thank you! Suppose we assume that $\Phi$ is Lipshitz continuous in the first variable, uniformly with respect to the second (so solutions are locally unique). How do we prove it then? I would like to take $c$ as in my proof above and fiddle a bit, but I can't seem to work it. I know that $f'(c) = g'(c)$, for example.

Comment: shouldt $f'<g'$ also give this? whats point of involving the function $\phi$ and then put $f$ in it?

Comment: @Vlad Without the nonlinearity of $\phi$, the problem becomes trivial. As to how the problem arises, well solutions to differential equations are common. Differential inequalities are less common, but they do occur. And then it is of interest to understand the consequences of such inequalities.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks, I thought some more about it, it is much less general to compare the function between each other since this would have to uniform over all $t$.Having this hypotheses instead is much more general.