# Prove that $\varphi(t) \geq \psi(t)$, for all $t\in I\cap J$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous functions such as $f(t,x)\geq g(t,x)$ for all $(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider $\varphi:I\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\psi:J\to\mathbb{R}$ solutions of the following Cauchy's problems. $x'(t)=f(t,x), x(0)=0$ and $y'(t)=g(t,y),y(0)=0$, respctively. Prove that $\varphi(t) \geq \psi(t)$, for all $t\in I\cap J$

My attempt: I've tried to create a system as follow:$z'(t)=f(t,x)-g(t,y), z(0)=0$. And now I don't know how to conclude. Any sugestions?

Comment: Under the assumption that $f$ is continuous only, the result is not true; see [Comparison theorem for ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912468/comparison-theorem-for-ode).

Comment: So, lets suposse that $f$ and $g$ are lipschitz continuous, I tried to use the demonstration that you recommended, but I can't compare $f$ and $g$

Answer (score 1):

Put $\zeta(t) := \psi(t) - \varphi(t)$ for $t \in I \cap J \cap [0, \infty)$.  We want to prove that $\zeta(t) \le 0$ for all $t \in I \cap J \cap [0, \infty)$.

Suppose to the contrary that there exists $c \in I \cap J \cap [0, \infty)$ such that $\zeta(c) > 0$.  Let $b := \sup\{t \in I \cap J \cap [0, c): \zeta(t) \le 0\}$.  By construction, $b \in [0, c)$ and $\zeta(t) > 0$ for all $t \in (b, c]$.

We have
$$
\zeta'(t) = \psi'(t) - \varphi'(t) = g(t, \psi(t)) - f(t, \varphi(t)) 
\\
= [g(t, \psi(t)) - g(t,\varphi(t))] + [g(t, \varphi(t)) - f(t, \varphi(t))] \le g(t, \psi(t)) - g(t,\varphi(t))
$$
for all $t \in I \cap J \cap [0, \infty)$.

By the (local) Lipschitz property of $g$ there exists $L > 0$ such that 
$$
\lvert g(t, \psi(t)) - g(t,\varphi(t)) \rvert \le L \lvert \psi(t) - \varphi(t) \rvert, \quad t \in [b, c],
$$
consequently,
$$
g(t, \psi(t)) - g(t,\varphi(t)) \le L (\psi(t) - \varphi(t)), \quad t \in [b, c].
$$
We have thus obtained that 
$$
\zeta'(t) - L \zeta(t) \le 0, \quad t \in [b, c],
$$
which gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{-Lt} \zeta(t)) \le 0, \quad t \in [b, c].
$$
Therefore
$$
\zeta(t) \le e^{L(t - b)} \zeta(b) = 0
$$
for all $t \in [b, c]$, a contradiction.

(The above proof is modeled on Theorem 9.IX on p. 96 of Wolfgang Walter's book [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387984593).)