# A question about a solution to an ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $I \subset \Bbb R$ be an interval and $λ : I → \Bbb R$ be a solution of the differential equation
$\dot x = f(t, x)$,
where $f : \Bbb R × \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ is continuous. Suppose that a differentiable function $α : I → \Bbb R$ satisfies
$\dot α(t) > f(t, α(t))$ for all $t \in I$, and we have $α(t_0) ≥ λ(t_0)$ for some $t_0 ∈ I$. Show that α(t) > λ(t) for
all $t ∈ I$  with  $t > t_0.$

Begining of the solution that I got : Define $d(t) := α(t) − λ(t)$ for all $t ∈ I$ with $t ≥ t_0$. The assumption implies that $d(t_0) ≥ 0$. Assume
for contradiction that d(t) ≤ 0 for some $t > t_0$ and define
$τ$ := inf { 
t > $t_0$ : d(t) ≤ 0}

My question is: why does this imply that $d(τ) = 0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison theorem for ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912468/comparison-theorem-for-ode)

Comment: @MartinR , I read it again and it actually answers my question, Thanks a lot for your time.