# Bound of an ODE using the Comparison Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given the IVP:   $\space y'(x)=y^2-x , y(0)=1$

I need to prove using the comparison theorem that for all $x\in[0,1): 1+x\le y(x)\le \frac{1}{1-x}$

The comparison theorem I'm referring to is this one: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912468/comparison-theorem-for-ode)

My try:

For RHS: We define the following IVP $y_1'(x)=y_1^2 , y_1(0)=1$. We have $y_1(x)= \frac{1}{1-x}$ and $y'(x)\le y_1'(x) \space \forall x\in[0,1)$. Thus, we can apply the comparison theorem to get $\space y(x)\le \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Would appreciate any help or direction to prove LHS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the way you are expected to solve this: treat it as Riccati equation, set $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$, then the associated second order linear DE is
$$
u''-xu=0,~~ u(0)=1,~~u'(0)=-1
$$
The power series coefficients obey $n(n-1)a_n=a_{n-3}$, $a_0=1$, $a_1=-1$, $a_2=0$, so that
$$
u(x)=1-x+\frac16x^3-\frac1{12}x^4+\frac1{180}x^6-\frac1{504}x^7\pm
$$
is an alternating series with rapidly falling coefficients for $x\le 1$. This results in the bounds by partial sums
$$
1-x\le u(x) \le 1\\
1-\frac12x^2\le -u'(x)\le 1
$$
so that combining the bounds
$$
\frac{1-\frac12x^2}{1-x+\frac16x^3}\le y(x) \le \frac1{1-x}.
$$
Now grind down on the left side for $x\in(0,1]$
$$
1+x\le\frac{1-\frac12x^2}{1-x+\frac16x^3}
\\
\iff
1-x^2+\frac16(x^3+x^4)\le 1-\frac12x^2
\\
\iff
x+x^2\le 3
$$
and as the last inequality is true on the interval, so is the first.