# How does the initial value of susceptible population affect the SIR model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

I have a question about the standard epidemic SIR model:
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\frac{\beta IS}{N},$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{\beta IS}{N}-\gamma I,$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\gamma I.$$
If all initial values ($I_0,R_0$) and parameters ($N,\beta,\gamma$) are the same, expect that we have two different initial $S$, i.e. $S_0>\hat{S}_0$, can we prove that $I(t)\geq\hat{I}(t)$ for any $t>0$?

The simulations show it is true.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this document and see if you can get some hints https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82254543.pdf. Also see this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912468/comparison-theorem-for-ode

Comment: You are violating $S+I+R=N$, which effectively changes $β$. You could possibly also start the analysis from this angle.